What are thick concrete blocks under cabin called?
What are these concrete slabs/blocks/pads called? They look similar to a patio slab, except they're thicker and used to elevate a cabin or other building off of the ground.


A general term for this is a "pier-and-beam" foundation. The concrete blocks are the piers. The horizontal piece of wood is a beam. Those concrete blocks should be cemented together, or replaced with a larger block. They look like they might slide eventually.

Useful terms:

Precast footings
Concrete foundation pads

Caveats about use of such products:

Substrate must be suitable inorganic soil. Black dirt and other unstable or uncompacted soils will allow severe settling.

Expect to have to jack and shim after rough construction. The weight of the building will probably cause some shifting.

Most building codes require frost footings to a depth appropriate for your climate. This isn't something to avoid because you can. It's good practice.



Yeah, if you're really stuck in a situation where you cannot dig down to the frost line, there's a better way to do it anyway (look up "shallow frost-protected foundation" for details)

In Ontario, Canada, they are often called "cottage pads," since they are most often used for cottage foundations.


Concrete Foundation Block
Concrete Footing Block

